# How to hide app already uploaded photos from gallery/photos app?

Tags: android, android-image, android-storage, android-photos

I have an app. It has the functionality of uploading photos from gallery/photos. **Is it possible to hide photos that have already been selected from gallery?**

For example:

- App doesn't have any photo uploaded yet.
- User accesses gallery/photos from app and user has possibility to select photo A, photo B, photo C, or/and photo D.
- User selects photo B, and photo C.
- User is redirected to app and photo B and photo C gets added to the app UI.
- User wants to add additional photos into app.
- User re-accesses gallery/photos, **but now user sees photo A, and photo D only**.

Comment: what you needed might require the customised media picker that should have the logic to hide or disable the image that you passed this media picker to hide. You save the selected image id and then while fetching the image again remove the image with the id that is already present in your app

Comment: I see. Does the Photo Picker https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#select-multiple-items need customization or is there any functionality that helps? So far, I couldn't find anything in it that hides already selected photos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can directory with(dot) so system will hides for example
.photo

Comment: can you please add more content?

Comment: yes, the android system creates any directory with (prefixes.) folder so system will hide all content for example

File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+".images");
directory.mkdirs();

so image folder with dot so hide it

Comment: @Vijay Red M want to access the gallery again but with the photo that is not selected already. What you suggested is hide the photo if it is added in a folder created using the code you shared

Comment: You can move your selected photos's (dot)f folder and same as get with (dot)folder